# Postgres Replication out of sync

Tags: postgresql, replication

We have master server on one Datacenter, and the Replicate is in another Datacenter

Intermittently, on the replicate server, we see this as below.

> “2018-12-19 07:24:25 UTC: : @: [25775]: [2-1] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
>   This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>   before or while processing the request.”

We have all DB (master and replicate settings) in place for streaming replication, and we are using the same settings on 100+ replicates and there is no issue except this.

I would appreciate if someone would help here.

1. we have wal_files on the master
2. hot_standy is on

When we initially start the replicate server, it streams, and if in case streaming is lagging, we have restore_command to restore from master pg_xlog_archive.

So, most of the time, we don't have issues, but sometimes we have this error.

Comment: Does it retry?  If so, does the retry succeed?

Comment: @McNets Sporadically it retries but sometimes the replicate DB server is just idle and in the wal file on the master is deleted and apparently, we have to rebuild the replicate from the pg_basebackup.